# Why does "puts 'foo'" and puts "foo\n" result in the same output in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, irb

This is from the irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> puts "abc"
abc
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> puts "abc\n"
abc
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts "abc\n\n"
abc

=> nil
```

As you can see, `puts "abc"` puts a newline after "abc", as it should. However, `puts "abc\n"` also puts a single newline, whereas I would expect that there would be two newlines.
To me, the output of `puts "abc\n\n"` is what I would expect from `puts "abc\n"`.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Did the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-i-puts) help? _"Writes a newline after any [given object(s)] that do not already end with a newline sequence"_

Comment: This does not seem to be an exact duplicate of the nominated exemplar.  The questions are quite different.

Comment: @Stefan, a quibble, or possibly a niggle: shouldn't your `puts` link be to [Kernel#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) rather than `IO#puts`, as `method(:puts).owner #=> Kernel` and `puts(o1,...)` is equivalent to `$stdout.puts(o1,...)` (`$stdout.class` being an instance of `IO`)? I'm not trying to catch you out (that would be a first), but to clarify for readers who are new to Ruby.

Comment: Above I wrote "`$stdout.class` being an instance of `IO`". Of course, it's `$stdout` that's an instance of `IO`. (I think I initially wrote `$stdout.class #=> IO` and messed up the edit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading Cary Swoveland's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726512/why-does-puts-foo-and-puts-foo-n-result-in-the-same-output-in-ruby?noredirect=1#comment76437010_44726512) I've realized that it is not at all obvious how `puts` works, because [its documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) is quite scarce:

> #### puts(obj, ...) → nil
>
> Equivalent to
>
> ```
> $stdout.puts(obj, ...)
> ```

It doesn't even bother to explain what `$stdout` is, nor does it provide a link.

`$stdout` is one of Ruby's pre-defined [global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html). It refers to the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) which in Ruby happens to be an instance of [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html):

```
$stdout
#=> #<IO:<STDOUT>>
```

So "Equivalent to `$stdout.puts(obj, ...)`" means that we have to read the documentation for [`IO#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> Writes the given object(s) to ios. Writes a newline after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. Returns `nil`.

There you go: `puts` only adds a newline if the object does not already ends with one.

To get the expected multi-line output, you can simply call `puts` for each line:

```
puts 'abc'
```

or

```
puts 'abc'
puts
```

or

```
puts 'abc'
puts
puts
```

Comment: There's also the constant `STDOUT`, the default value of `$stdout`. That makes it convenient to change the value of `$stdout` then later change it back to the default.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how `puts` works. It prevents you from needing to append a newline everytime you call `puts`.

Given no newline, one will be added
Given a trailing newline, an additional one will not be added

Source: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-i-puts